# Bootstrap 3 - Long form with different sections - full width background

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, markup

I started using Bootstrap 3 and have a really long form. I would like to separate each section with different full width background color, and I'm curious what the correct markup would be.

Should it be something like following?

```
<form>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                 <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</form>
```

Comment: It looks like you aren't using the bootstrap grid model correctly. Basically it splits a row into 12 columns (or splits a sub component 12 ways) so having col-xs-12 and col-md-4 on the same element doesn't really make sense. Take a look at the documentation at http://getbootstrap.com/css/ to see how the grid model works

Comment: Hmmm, please see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed - looks like I'm doing exactly that... Anyway, my question is about the fullwidth form layout...

Comment: Seems you're right, so I've learned something then! Sorry. I'm not sure the full width background colour for each section you talk about can be implied just from the markup here so I guess you'd be implementing some CSS class of your own on the outer div to achieve that right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry if it is late, but was looking for something similar. Found [Panels](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#panels) utility inside basic bootstrap and worked for me. Hope could help someone.

Comment: And Cards in versión 4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/

Comment: You can use **fieldsets**. [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-disabled-fieldsets](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-disabled-fieldsets)